# Ionic - SubprocessError with 'ionic cordova platform resources ios'

Tags: node.js, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to generate the resources for an ionic project. Unfortunately, that doesn't go very well.
Cordova works just fine when I'm trying to add the ios platform, but it's giving me this error when I'm generating the resources (icon/splash).

I already re-installed the ionic scripts, cordova and re-added the platforms, as said in other threads with approximately the same problem as I have.

This is my ionic/cordova info.

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.0.2
   Ionic Framework               : not installed
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : not installed
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : not installed
   @angular/cli                  : not installed
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : not installed

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : browser 5.0.4
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.3.2, (and 6 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.9.4
   NodeJS     : v12.11.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.11.3
   OS         : macOS Catalina
   Xcode      : Xcode 11.2 Build version 11B52
```

The result when executing the command:

> ionic cordova resources ios --force

```
Error

at new SubprocessError (//node_modules/@ionic/utils-subprocess/dist/index.js:40:23)
at ChildProcess.<anonymous>
(//node_modules/@ionic/utils-subprocess/dist/index.js:113:27)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:270:12)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

Comment: You can add `--verbose` to the command to get more information.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer here?

Answer (score 0):

Delete node_modules folder and package-lock.json file and then run

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it fixed for me after install cordova-res with below command

```
npm install -g cordova-res
```

Hope it will help :)